# How to make a single 256*256*N (double) .mat from multiple .png image

Tags: matlab, for-loop, png, transform, mat

There are 100 PNG images,size=256*256,channel=1
Here is my test code(test for save 2 images in a mat):

```
label = {sprintf('%01d.png\n', 0:100)};
img = regexp(label{:}(1:end-1), '\n', 'split');
F1=im2double(imread(img{1}));
F2=im2double(imread(img{2}));
label=cat(1,F1,F2);`
save('test.mat', 'label')
```

-> The test.mat is 256X256X2 double

However,I want to save 100 images in the mat.
My idea is F1~100 <=> 1~100.png then cat(1,F1,F2...F100),and save at last.
So I try to use eval() in for loop create F1~100 to load 1~100.png correspondingly
like this:

```
for i=1:100
    eval(["F",num2str(c),"=",im2double(imread(img_names{c}))]);
end
```

But it's not work.
Any solution for this problem?

Comment: You are trying to use dynamic variable names (i.e. creating variables on the fly). There is no enough space in Stackoverflow to explain how terrible, terrible idea that is. Just make 1 matrix, store images in the 3rd dim, as your title suggests.

Comment: Ok,I see. Thanks for the reminder. I use`F=cell(1,100)` and `F{i}=im2double(imread(img_names{i}));` and `label=cat(3,F{:});` at last. It work fine.

Comment: But I don't know if there any bug or mistake in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just preallocate your matrix:

```
last=im2double(imread(img_names{c}))
F(:,:,length(img_names))=last;
```

then just loop and fill

```
for i=1:100
    F(:,:,i)=im2double(imread(img_names{i}));
end
```

This will only work for images that are the same size, and grayscale images.

NOTE: eval is the worst MATLAB function and its highly discouraged by Mathworks themselves. Never use it.