# Is there a way to increase a non array integer in matlab?

Tags: matlab

A partial issue with my question is I don't know enough computer science terms to ask it succinctly so hopefully this example code helps:

Say I have this code:

```
    a1 = 1;
    a2 = 2;
    a3 = 3;
```

I want to be really lazy and have the variable "a" increase in a 'for loop'.

```
    for(i=1:3)
            ai = i
    end
```

where this should equal; a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 3. Is this possible in matlab? What is this called?

Comment: you can do it, but why? that's why we have arrays. so array `a` will be such that it's first element `a(1)=1`, its n-th element `a(n)=n` etc... Creating n variables is pretty useless and clogs the workspace with too many names, where a single array of n elements will do.

Comment: I answered this today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63029442/how-to-make-a-single-256256n-double-mat-from-multiple-png-image#comment111460663_63029442

Comment: There are no " non-array integers" in MATLAB, all variables are arrays. In your case, the arrays are 1x1. Do as @bla says, use `a(1)` instead of `a1`. Then you can loop over the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try `assignin` like below

```
for i = 1:3
  assignin('base',sprintf("a%d",i),i);
end
```

---

If you are using it within a function, you may need

```
for i = 1:3
  assignin('caller',sprintf("a%d",i),i);
end
```

Comment: Do note that this doesn't work if you need these variables to exist in the current workspace. This only works to put variables in the base workspace, so is only useable from within a script, not a function.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, this is for the case of base workspace

Answer (score 0):

ThomasisCoding and Ander Biguri provided great answers.

Thanks for all the help! Code I ended up using:

```
a = (zeros(13,1));
for i = 1:numberoffiles
    v = num2str(i)
    formatspec1 = '%s%s';
    d = sprintf(formatspec1,'filename',v);
    a(i,:) = string(eval(d));
end
```

Comment: Please don't use `eval`. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html

Comment: Cris, thanks for your comment and I agree with you. I have also found alternative methods for my coding goals and honestly don't remember why I used eval. Some functions that I found more useful that eventually led me to other, better solutions: strcat. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future who discovers this thread. Cheers!